# squashing multiple table results into unique rows based on an id

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to combine the results of multiple table results into one. The idea is to display data for a multi-line graph on the UI. The result would be something like 
[date time] | pressure | flow | consumption
Each of the 3 columns (pressure, flow, consumption) are all coming from different table, but they would share a similar datetime field - since we want to display those points for that time.

I thought possibly doing a union all would help combine the results, but that doesn't seem to do much. I am seeing online to use pivot? but am not sure if that would work in this case.

For example, I am doing the following. One option is to include all the expected result rows (all 3 types) in each clause so that we could somehow "SQUASH" them together based on "datelabel" and leave null if it does not exist for that hour.

```
            select deviceid, min(flowrate),
            to_char(recorded, 'Mon-dd hh:00 pm') as datelabel
            from analytic.pressureflow p
             WHERE (deviceid = 162300) and flowtype = 'MIN'
             AND recorded >= '9/16/2019 11:24:00 AM' 
             AND recorded < '9/24/2019 11:24:00 AM' 
             group by deviceid, datelabel
            ), --select * from min_flow


            max_flow as (
             select deviceid, MAX(flowrate),
             to_char(recorded, 'Mon-dd hh:00 pm') as datelabel
            from analytic.pressureflow p
             WHERE (deviceid = 162300) and flowtype = 'MAX'
             AND recorded >= '9/16/2019 11:24:00 AM' 
             AND recorded < '9/24/2019 11:24:00 AM' 
             group by deviceid, datelabel
            ), -- select * from max_flow


            flow_temp as (
            select deviceid, avg(flowtemp) as flowtemp,
            null as tempvalue,
            to_char(recorded, 'Mon-dd hh:00 pm') as datelabel
             from twflowtemperature
             WHERE (deviceid = 162300)
             AND recorded >= '9/16/2019 11:24:00 AM' 
             AND recorded < '9/18/2019 11:24:00 AM' 
             group by deviceid, datelabel
             ), -- select * from flow_temp

              device_temp as (
                    select 
                    deviceid, 
                    tempvalue,
                    timestamp as recorded
                     from twdevicetemp
                     WHERE (deviceid = 162300)
                     AND timestamp >= '9/16/2019 11:24:00 AM' 
                     AND timestamp < '9/18/2019 11:24:00 AM' 

             ), --  select * from ambient_temp

             ambient_temp as (
              select 
                    deviceid, 
                    avg(tempvalue) as tempvalue,
                    null as flowtemp,
                    to_char(recorded, 'Mon-dd hh:00 pm') as datelabel
                    from device_temp
                    group by deviceid, datelabel
             )

             select * from ambient_temp
             union all
             select * from flow_temp
```

The main question: Is it possible to squash rows together based on an ID ( in this case the date time string)?

```
Headers: datetime   |  pressure   |   flow    |   consumption
         9/27 1PM        1.5           null         200
         9/27 2PM   |     2            10           50
         9/27 3pm   |   null           null          null
```

ETC ETC.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for join:

```
select coalesce(pressure.datetime, flow.datetime, consumption.datetime),
   pressure, flow, consumption
from (
   -- your pressure query here
) pressure
full outer join (
   -- your flow query here
) flow on flow.datetime=pressure.datetime
full outer join (
   -- your consumption query here
) consumption on consumption.datetime = isnull(flow.datetime,pressure.datetime)
```

Comment: Fantastic. I see what you did. Also I did not think to use coalesce to get the time.

Comment: Also - is there a way to fill in the gaps? Like if no table has data for a specific hour to also include it as a null row?

Comment: You'll have to create a table that is populated with each hour you are interested in and then full join that table into the rest.  There are a lot of examples on how to fill in missing dates (that you should be able to extrapolate to hours).  There are also a lot of examples on how to create such a table (often using a recursive CTE).